# How do I skip the Switch User screen in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, hotkeys

I have Vista Home Premium and I just want it to work like XP.  In XP if you hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it goes to the user selection screen.  Vista puts an extra "Switch User" screen in.  I'd prefer not to retrain the whole house to use [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/17/shortcut-to-switch-user-in-windows-vista/).  Is there a registry key or security policy setting for this?

---

**Update:**

No complete solution, but I settled for the workaround mentioned above.  Using the method described [here](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2008/01/17/shortcut-to-switch-user-in-windows-vista/), I downloaded a file called [SwitchUser.exe](http://dotsmart.net/files/SwitchUser.zip) written by Duncan Smart.  Following Factor's advice, I installed Autohotkey and created the instruction:

```
#l::Run SwitchUser.exe
```

Autohotkey is scheduled to load for all users.  Windows-L will now take the users to the user selection screen.  One glitch is that when the screen saver is interrupted it returns to the "Switch User" screen instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a hotkey program (like AutoHotKey, HoeKey, etc) to remap Win+L to Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L?

Comment: +1 It took 3 weeks, but so far my users are happy, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

As factor suggested, a hotkey is probably the best way to imitate this behavior, and here is the code for [**AutoHotkey**](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
#l::{Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Shift Down}{L Down}{Ctrl up}{Alt up}{Shift up}{L up}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to disable [Fast User Switching](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-vista/disable-fast-user-switching-in-vista/).  That way, you will just have your "normal" login.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might work as well:

Force as close to the the "classic" logon as Vista can get:

Start -> Control Panel -> System and Maintenance -> Administrative
Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Local Policy -> Security
Options

- "Interactive logon: Do not display last user name" = Enabled
- "Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL" = Disabled

Start -> gpedit.msc -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon

- Hide entry points for Fast User Switching = Enabled
- Always use classic logon = enabled

Note: this probably doesn't work if your in a domain!

According to the comments it doesn't work for Vista Home Premium, so you have to install a [tweaking program like TweakVista](http://www.tweakvista.com/tweakvistautility/) which will give you the option to only require a password to log in.

[image]

Comment: I tried all 4 of these registry keys (VHP lacks secpol and gpedit) and none worked.  Thanks, though.

Comment: You could try installing TweakUI for Vista, but I can't find a good HowTo.